# Como habilitar el "productio.mode" in angular2 con Angular-cli?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Cuando se crea un proyecto nuevo con angular-cli por default no esta habilitado para ejecutar en productio.mode ¿Como se puede habilitar?

El archivo main.ts generado es el siguiente:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

console.log("environment.production:" + environment.production);

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Y el resultado de la impresión en el log es:

```
environment.production:false
```

¿Como se habilitaría la variable de entorno para producción?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng build --target=production --environment=prod
```

Puedes ampliar la info aquí: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

También puedes hacer:
    ng serve --environment=prod 
Para probar en local

Answer (score 1):

Agrega la siguiente entrada en tu archivo **angular-cli.json**:

```
"environments": {
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

Crea una carpeta llamada **environments** dónde deberías tener el siguiente código:

```
export const environment = {
  production: true
};
```

Y compilalo con:

```
ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

En *angular-cli* ya viene configurado en el directorio **src/environments**.

En el archivo **environment.ts** deberías tener lo siguiente:

```
export const environment = {production: false}
```

Solo debes cambiarla a como sigue:

```
export const environment = {production: true}
```

Y ya tienes el modo producción activado.